# Open Cv assertion failed

Tags: python, opencv, facial-landmark-alignment

trying to detect face landmarks using openCv, the error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aksheenmalhotra/Desktop/gaze controlled/gazecontrolledkeys.py", line 13, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

what could be the possible error? and how to solve, was getting similar error for other openCv project  as well

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import dlib
cap = cv2.VideoCapture()

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")
cap.release()
def midpoint(p1 ,p2):
    return int((p1.x + p2.x)/2), int((p1.y + p2.y)/2)
while True:
    ref, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = detector(gray)
    for face in faces:
        #x, y = face.left(), face.top()
        #x1, y1 = face.right(), face.bottom()
        #cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x1, y1), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        center_top = midpoint(landmarks.part(37), landmarks.part(38))
        center_bottom = midpoint(landmarks.part(41), landmarks.part(40))
        hor_line = cv2.line(frame, left_point, right_point, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        ver_line = cv2.line(frame, center_top, center_bottom, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Does this (and dozens of similar Q&As) answer your question? [OpenCV !\_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676020/opencv-src-empty-in-function-cvtcolor-error) Check, if `ref` is `True`, and/or if `frame` is not `None`, before passing `frame` to `cv2.cvtColor`!

Answer (score 0):

This type error occurs because of non-able to load your frames. This topic also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676020/opencv-src-empty-in-function-cvtcolor-error).

In your case, your **VideoCapture()** is reading nothing. You should add a camera number as *int* like : **VideoCapture(0)** which calls the default camera.

[This example](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) is good to start  with.