# Opencv (in python) gives error - !_src.empty() in function 'cv2::cvtColor '

Tags: python, opencv

I'm currently trying to run a simple python program to detect face and eyes.

I downloaded the appropriate classifiers and they're in the same directory. I even checked my camera settings and it's set to on with permission to python. Any ideas how to solve this?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
   ret, img = cap.read()
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
   for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
      cv2.rectange(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
      roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
      roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
      eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
      for (ex,ey,ew,ehh) in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex,ey), (ex+ew,ey+eh), (0,255,0), 2)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
if k == 27:
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Why does this OpenCV program give the **error**:

[image: !_src.empty() error in function 'cv::cvtColor']

My **camera settings** show that python is using it: 
[image: Camera settings' screenshot]

Thank you!

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Googling that exact error message (e.g. python opencv src.empty) game [this top result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676020/opencv-src-empty-in-function-cvtcolor-error). I searched your cvt.VideoCapture and found [this, which discusses how to debug if it initialized the capture](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html). I'd say verify it is initialized and edit your question with what you find out.

Answer (score 1):

!_src.empty() means you have an empty frame

You can check the frame to make sure you actually get the image:

```
ret, img = cap.read()
if img is not None: 
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
else: < implement how you want to deal with empty frame >
```