# error: (-215:Assertion failed) while using openCV

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, anaconda

```
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    face = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in face:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 255), 2)

        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        eye = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eye:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex,ey),(ex+ew, ey_eh), (0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imshow('Face', frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if k ==27:
        break


    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()
```

I keep getting this error

> error: OpenCV(3.4.5)
>   /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:181:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'

Comment: please provide the full error traceback

Comment: The problem seems `frame`. It is either empty or malformed.

Comment: You most likely have a problem with your webcam.  OpenCV can't access its stream.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV !\_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676020/opencv-src-empty-in-function-cvtcolor-error)

Comment: VideoCapture read() method returns the boolean value for success/failure of frame read - underscore in your code. It is a good practise to use the value and to handle the error yourself in your code.

Comment: How can I check if OpenCV has granted permission to access my webcam in Mac?

Comment: I'm using anaconda with TensorFlow and Keras

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred when the frame couldn't load into cv2 properly. Because the images in the frame are corrupted or it does not support the cv2 or the image's size is large. Sometimes this error can be solved by using exception handling with try, except blocks. Try printing those images, then you can get an idea of whether the images in the frame support cv2 or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had same problem while doing image template matching, it occurred when image is not correctly loaded. In my case I put wrong filename extention. try to capture the shape of frame