# Error when I try to use my webcam (python)

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, video-capture

So, I'm using jupyter in a facial detection project, and when I run the program , this message error appears:

```
> (error: OpenCV(4.2.0)
> C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function
> 'cv::cvtColor') [enter image description here][1]
```

This is the code:

[image]
Thank you !

Comment: How about checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676020/opencv-src-empty-in-function-cvtcolor-error) case? looks helpful.

Comment: I already read this post but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when `frame` is empty = image was not captured. You are not checking if `video_capture` is correctly opened before using `video_capture.read()`. Try to check if `read()` returned frame:

```py
...
retval, frame = video_capture.read()
if (!retval):
   print("Error when capturing frame")
   continue # loop until retval is true

gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
...
```

The problem can have more causes:

- camera is not responding
- there are more cameras and you initialized wrong camera id
- camera is slow and first few frames are empty/not read

You can identify if it is faulty camera by loading picture with `cv2.imread()` before `cv2.cvtColor()` into frame and processing it, if it works, then try to troubleshoot `video_capture` initialization and camera.

TL;DR: `frame` is empty when calling `cv2.cvtColor()`, ensure/check that it isn't

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2 
import uuid
import os
import time
labels = ['pistol','knife','rifle','shotgun']
number_imgs = 5
```

   By using above code lables are created so that pictures will be saved in respective folders and number_imgs is number of images to be taken.

```
IMAGES_PATH = os.path.join('Tensorflow', 'workspace', 'images', 'collectedimages')
```

   By using the above code we are defining the path.

```
if not os.path.exists(IMAGES_PATH):
if os.name == 'posix':
    !mkdir -p {IMAGES_PATH}
if os.name == 'nt':
     !mkdir {IMAGES_PATH}
for label in labels:
path = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH, label)
if not os.path.exists(path):
    !mkdir {path}
```

   The Images path will be created inside virtual environment by using the above code.

```
for label in labels:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
print('Collecting images for {}'.format(label))
time.sleep(5)
for imgnum in range(number_imgs):
    print('Collecting image {}'.format(imgnum))
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    imgname = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH,label,label+'.'+'{}.jpg'.format(str(uuid.uuid1())))
    cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    time.sleep(2)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break 
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

   By using the above code the camera will open and take pictures and saved them automatically in the specified folders inside the virtual environment.