# OpenCV code in google colab results in assertion error

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, opencv

```
while(True):

    ret,img=source.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=face_clsfr.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-141c55e32dfe> in <module>()
      2 
      3     ret,img=source.read()
----> 4     gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      5     faces=face_clsfr.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
      6 

error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676020/opencv-src-empty-in-function-cvtcolor-error
Looks like the image probably wasn't read correctly. 
You'd need to show where `source` is defined to know what's going wrong.

Comment: Please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed), and it should not be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter (edited out).

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says „assertion failed...  src.empty“. print out your values for ret and img. I am sure img might be None type or „“ or something similar.