# What is the reason for this error? (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'

Tags: python, keras, google-colaboratory, opencv

```
OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'.
```

What is the reason of error here?

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    from keras.layers import Conv2D, Input, ZeroPadding2D, BatchNormalization, Activation, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense
    from keras.models import Model, load_model
    from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
    from sklearn.utils import shuffle
    import cv2
    import imutils
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import time
    from os import listdir
    import pickle
    import joblib
    
    %matplotlib inline
    
    
    
    def crop_brain_contour(image, plot=False):
        
        grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        grayscale = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayscale, (5, 5), 0)
        threshold_image = cv2.threshold(grayscale, 45, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
        threshold_image = cv2.erode(threshold_image, None, iterations=2)
        threshold_image = cv2.dilate(threshold_image, None, iterations=2)
    
        contour = cv2.findContours(threshold_image.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contour = imutils.grab_contours(contour)
        c = max(contour, key=cv2.contourArea)
        
        extreme_pnts_Left = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
        extreme_pnts_Right = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
        extreme_pnts_Top = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
        extreme_pnts_Bot = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
        
        new_image = image[extreme_pnts_Top[1]:extreme_pnts_Bot[1], extreme_pnts_Left[0]:extreme_pnts_Right[0]]            
    
        if plot:
            plt.figure()
    
            plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
            plt.imshow(image)
            
            plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', 
                            top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False,
                            labelbottom=False, labeltop=False, labelleft=False, labelright=False)
            
            plt.title('Original Image')
                
            plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
            plt.imshow(new_image)
    
            plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', 
                            top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False,
                            labelbottom=False, labeltop=False, labelleft=False, labelright=False)
    
            plt.title('Cropped Image')
            
            plt.show()
        
        return new_image
    
    
    
    
    ex_img = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/Alzheimer/Alzheimer_s Dataset/train/MildDemented/mildDem0.jpg')
    ex_new_img = crop_brain_contour(ex_img, True)
    
    
    
    
    ex_img = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/Alzheimer/Alzheimer_s Dataset/train/MildDemented/mildDem0.jpg')
    ex_new_img = crop_brain_contour(ex_img, True)
    
    
    
    def load_data(dir_list, image_size):
        
    
        X = []
        y = []
        image_width, image_height = image_size
        
        for directory in dir_list:
            for filename in listdir(directory):
                print(directory + '/' + filename)
    
                image = cv2.imread(directory + '/' + filename)
                
                image = crop_brain_contour(image, plot=False)
    
    
                image = image / 255.
    
                X.append(image)
    
                if directory[-3:] == 'train':
                    y.append([1])
                else:
                    y.append([0])
                    
        X = np.array(X)
        y = np.array(y)
        
        X, y = shuffle(X, y)
        
        print(f'Number of examples is: {len(X)}')
        print(f'X shape is: {X.shape}')
        print(f'y shape is: {y.shape}')
        
        return X, y
    
    
    
    
    Alzheimer_s_Dataset = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Alzheimer/Alzheimer_s Dataset/'
    
    Alzheimer_s_Dataset_train = Alzheimer_s_Dataset + 'train' 
    Alzheimer_s_Dataset_test = Alzheimer_s_Dataset + 'test'
    
    IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT = (128, 128)
    #loading dataset
    X, y = load_data([Alzheimer_s_Dataset_train, Alzheimer_s_Dataset_test], (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT))
```

After this it is showing cvtColor error. If anyone know the reason and how to solve it please let me know?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV !\_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676020/opencv-src-empty-in-function-cvtcolor-error)

Comment: `imread()` doesn't raise error when file doesn't exist but it gives `None` and you have to check if you get `None` before you try to modify image.

Comment: No, I got the error only at the end when I am trying to load dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error when you are attempting to use the `cv2.cvtColor()` method on an empty image. Observe:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> import numpy as np
>>> img = np.uint8([])
>>> img
array([], dtype=uint8)
>>> cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) /tmp/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'

>>>
```

The likely cause of empty images in your code is that you used the `cv2.imread()` method on a path that doesn't exist. Make sure that your paths are correctly defined, and one way to do this is to use the [`os.path.exists()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) method:

```
>>> import os
>>> path = "Folder/images/1.png"
>>> if os.path.exists(path):
...     img = cv2.imread(path)
... else:
...     print("Path does not exist:", path)
... 
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

- This error occurs when function works on a  null input, probably because the input wasn't inputted properly. Try printing the image and check if it is not a null value.
- In the load data function where you are calling the `crop_brain_contour` function make sure you are passing the directory of the image correctly.
- Try modifying your code to even include the extension of the image and make sure to enter the correct directory. Try changing your code to:
  `image = cv2.imread(directory + '/' + filename + 'extension_of_the_image')`

Comment: I tried doing this but it's still not working

Comment: `print(image)` in the first line of the `crop_brain_contour` function and let me know the output.

Comment: It's not doing anything other than printing arrays in the output.

Comment: [https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rWcMseeLaNson9TJJcYjuNjR0-bsPgOq?authuser=1#scrollTo=39rMWe6mcgGz&uniqifier=2] Here is the link to the code

Comment: The colab file is private. Please give access to the colab file.

Comment: Check now I have given the access

Comment: It works fine when I tried to run it using random images. I also have tried to run it using an image  from alzheimer dataset from kaggle and it works properly when i ran it.

Comment: You used colab for this?

Comment: yes, i used colab. You can see the changes i made and the corresponding outputs in the same colab link.