# OpenCV Error: 215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Tags: python, opencv, cvzone

I do not use to work with python, and I a need your help.
This is my code:

```
import cv2
from cvzone.PoseModule import PoseDetector

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Video.mp4')

detector = PoseDetector()
posList = []
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    img = detector.findPose(img)                        /*Here is the error*/
    lmList, bboxInfo = detector.findPosition(img)

    if bboxInfo:
        lmString = ''
        for lm in lmList:
            lmString += f'{lm[1]},{img.shape[0] - lm[2]},{lm[3]},'
        posList.append(lmString)

    print(len(posList))

    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('s'):
        with open("AnimationFile.txt", 'w') as f:
            f.writelines(["%s\n" % item for item in posList])
```

The error is: 215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

I've read some forums, but I could't find a solution

I try with:

```
if img is not None:
```

and

```
import cv2
from cvzone.PoseModule import PoseDetector

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Video.mp4')

detector = PoseDetector()
posList = []
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    if not success:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    img = detector.findPose(img)
    lmList, bboxInfo = detector.findPosition(img)
```

Comment: so you *tried*, but what *happened* then?

Comment: Where is cvtColor in your code? Can you please provide the full error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [imread returns None, violating assertion !\_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676020/imread-returns-none-violating-assertion-src-empty-in-function-cvtcolor-er)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I tried and it didn't work. just the print funtion

Comment: @tintin98 this is the complete error:


  Mensaje = OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

  Origen = C:\Users\Dixlan\Desktop\UNITY PROYECTS\Python\Motion Capture\Motion_Capture.py
  Seguimiento de la pila:
  File "C:\Users\Dixlan\Desktop\UNITY PROYECTS\Python\Motion Capture\Motion_Capture.py", line 10, in <module> (Current frame)
    img = detector.findPose(img)